# SuperUser.com shares cookies with other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

I don't often come to SuperUser, but a lot on Travel.SE, Apple,SE, and various others.  Typically, if I go from XX.stackexchange.com to YY.stackexchange.com, I remain logged in.  And when I open a browser for the first time after a boot or a non-SE site, I am automatically logged in.  I assumed that was done by cookies.

Today, I tried to make a comment on SuperUser, and had to log in.  That is not a surprise, since it is a different domain.  But when I went from there to Travel.SE, I was logged out.

What is the mechanism involved here?

Comment: Could be that logging into a new site refreshed your OpenID token which meant it would invalidate the old token. You would then have to refresh the other sites to make them use the new token as well. Not completely sure though, a developer would know better. Might happen if you've not had to log in for some time... I had something similar a week or two ago.

Comment: There are occasional network/software glitches on the SE network that seem to randomly log you out from either the main sites or chat. Usually logging back in resolves the issue.